# How can get a count return anonymous object in Json

Tags: c#, .net-core

Here I need number of school count on the basis of school system Id.

```
public async Task<ICollection<SchoolCountVm>> GetSchoolCountBySchoolSystemId(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
 var schools = _GpsContext.School.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SchoolSystemsID == schoolSystemId).Count();
  return ok(new { count = schools }); // Here problem is showing
  }
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an `IActionResult` type, but your signature is `Task<ICollection<SchoolCountVm>>`

This mismatch shows the error when you return the `ok` function.

Try with this:

```
public IActionResult GetSchoolCountBySchoolSystemId(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
  var schools = _GpsContext.School.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.SchoolSystemsID == schoolSystemId).Count();
  return ok(new { count = schools }); // Here problem is showing
}
```

There is an async flavor too if you need it.

You can check the following guide for action return types:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> The IActionResult return type is appropriate when multiple ActionResult return types are possible in an action. The ActionResult types represent various HTTP status codes. Any non-abstract class deriving from ActionResult qualifies as a valid return type. Some common return types in this category are BadRequestResult (400), NotFoundResult (404), and OkObjectResult (200). Alternatively, convenience methods in the ControllerBase class can be used to return ActionResult types from an action. For example, return BadRequest(); is a shorthand form of return new BadRequestResult();.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [@Athanasios Kataras answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59798742/5519709) or if you don't want to change signature then return `Task<SchoolCountVm>` instead of `Task<ICollection<SchoolCountVm>>` from your `GetSchoolCountBySchoolSystemId` method:

I assume that in `SchoolCountVm` model you have property as `Count`:

```
public async Task<SchoolCountVm> GetSchoolCountBySchoolSystemId(Guid schoolSystemId)
{
    var schoolCount = await _GpsContext.School.AsNoTracking()
                        .Where(x => x.SchoolSystemsID == schoolSystemId)
                        .CountAsync();

    return new SchoolCountVm() { Count = schoolCount };
}
```

Comment: You assume that in SchoolCountVm model have property as Count is correct, I am creating API through repository pattern, so can't be use @Athanasios Kataras answer that is solution for MVC. But in your code here still showing following error: CS1061 'Schools' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no accessible extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'Schools' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)